# How do I to create a specific class to open the Detail of NavigationPages?

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to create a specific Class where it will concentrate open of my pages, this Class has a method to open the Detail of NavigationPage but it always throws an exception that I don't know how to fix.

How could I fix this ?

**Call the Class to open Detail**

```
private void ListViewClick(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs args){
            MenuItem item = args.Item as MenuItem;
            IsPresented = false;
            new OpenPage().open(item.Id);                    
        }
```

**Specific Class will open Detail of NavigationPage**

```
public class OpenPage : MasterDetailPage{
    public void open(int id){  
        Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage());
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I've just passed the MasterDetailPage as a parameter and finally it works as I want. My solution is below

```
public class OpenPage{
    public void open(int id, MasterDetailPage mdp){
        switch (id){
            case 0:
                mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new ProdutosUsuarioView());
                break;
        }        
    }

}//close class
```